# Greedy match unless it runs into specific string, then match to specific group?

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds, logstash-grok, regex-greedy

I'm trying to parse a URL in logstash using regex/grok. I've figured out most of the string, but I'm stuck on the last part, which i've found difficult to explain:

Here is the part I'm stuck on:

In Logstash, I would like to capture this whole string and dump it into a field called  `api_info`, UNLESS it contains the string `&freeText=`, in which case I want everything up until `&freeText=`  to go into the `api_info`  field, and everything after the `&freeText=` to go into the `api_search` field. Otherwise, the api_search field should be null.

Here's what I have so far/ have tried:

```
(?<api_info>.*?)(?=&freeText=)?(:?&freeText=)(?<api_search>.*)?
(?<api_info>.*)((:?&freeText=)(?<api_search>.*))?
```

Input string:
`womens%7cshoes%ctrainer&pageSize=60&freeText=shoes30`

expected input/output:

```
womens%7cshoes%ctrainer&pageSize=60&freeText=shoes30
api_info:"womens%7cshoes%ctrainer&pageSize=60", api_search:"shoes30"
mens%7trainers&pageSize=90
api_info:"mens%7trainers&pageSize=90", api_search:null
```

Comment: Why not simply split string with `&freeText` and decide api_search based on splited values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note sure if an empty group converts to null, but you might use an alternation to match  either the end of the string `$` or `&freeText=`

For the api_search group, you could match any char 0+ times.

```
(?<api_info>.+?)(?:&freeText=|$)(?<api_search>.*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<api_info>.+?)` Group `api_info`, match any char except newline 1+ times
- `(?:&freeText=|$)` Match either `&freeText=` or assert end of string
- `(?<api_search>.*)` Group `api_search`, match any char except newline 0+ times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xwXT6t/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a positive lookahead, it is never going to match the second message. So use alternation

```
"((?<api_info>.*)(&freeText=)(?<api_search>.*)?|(?<api_info>.*))"
```